# iOS6 vs iOS7, UITableViewCell Swipe Deleting Issue

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uitableview, ios7, xcode5

I am working on an app which supports on iOS6 & iOS7. 
The UITableViewCell swipe and delete functionality is working fine in both directions (Right To Left, Left To Right) on iOS6. But on iOS7, only One direction(Right To Left) is working.
Is APPLE removed that supportability? or i need to add any small code for that? or Need to overwrite the swipe functionality for UITableViewCell?

Any comments or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060032/swipe-left-or-right-anywhere-in-a-uitableviewcell-to-delete-the-cell-with-no-del

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple removed the ability to swipe left for deletion in iOS 7, and if you think about the difference between the delete buttons in 6/7 and how they appear in the cell this makes a lot of sense.

And yes, if you really want to add the left gesture just subclass the cell and add a left swipe gesture.

Comment: Thanks.....yes the direction makes sense in iOS7..but it is client requirement....i can't see your name...it is showing as 0x7ffffff...

Comment: @AshokKumar.S haha that is my name! :)

Comment: @Ox7ffffff.. I subclassed the Cell and added the left swipe to cell...now which action i should assign to that swipe gesture to appear the delete button on cell's right side as same as the default UITableViewCell right swipe gesture does in iOS7. Can you provide some guidelines..

Answer (score 1):

The delete swipe is from that direction in iOS7, you can create your own gesture recogniser if you want that functionality.